# How to make a button to start a quiz?

Tags: eclipse

I'm making this quiz app for my college final task this semester using eclipse. So there would be the first frame (?) that contains a button where when you click it, you will start the quiz. But I don't know how to make the quiz starts when I click the button. I've watched several videos and searching but still to no avail.

Maybe someone has a link to some solution or maybe someone want to directly answer it?

Thank you very much to every answers and comments!

(The app I use is Eclipse Indigo)

Comment: Hi Beatri, firstly, which programming language are you wanting to use? Java?

Comment: Eclipse is a development environment which supports many different programming languages - which one are you asking about?

Comment: I'm using java in this app.